# Parallel Document Conversion ODT > PDF Libreoffice

Tags: python, bash, libreoffice

I am converting hundreds of ODT files to PDF files, and it takes a long time doing one after the other. I have a CPU with multiple cores. Is it possible to use bash or python to write a script to do these in parallel?
Is there a way to parallelize (not sure if I'm using the right word) batch document conversion using libreoffice from the command line?
I have been doing it in python/bash calling the following commands:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf *appsmergeme.odt
```

OR

```
subprocess.call(str('cd $HOME; libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf *appsmergeme.odt'), shell=True);
```

Thank you!

Tim

Comment: Do you mean to run a single `libreoffice` command on multiple CPUs or make multiple calls to `libreoffice` and convert the files separately? In the first case you can't do anything, in the second case it is simple.

Comment: Uhm, I believe `libreoffice` prevents you to run more than a pdf converter concurrently. Trying to create multiple processes only generate a single `.pdf` file and the other processes fail. This happen even when using the `--nolockcheck` option. So, I believe the answer to your question is: you can't. You should use a different program for the conversion.

Comment: I believe I once read that libreoffice always uses only one process (also across writer, impress etc.), that would make this probably impossible.

Comment: Bkuriu: I mean to run libreoffice on multiple CPUs so that multiple files can be converted at the same time.

Comment: Any recommendations for doing batch conversions from the CLI ODT > PDF besides Libreoffice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run libreoffice as a daemon/service. Please check the following link, maybe it helps you too: [Daemonize the LibreOffice service](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/blog/sag47-492023/headless-file-conversion-using-libreoffice-as-a-service-35310/)

Other posibility is to use [unoconv](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv). "unoconv is a command line utility that can convert any file format that OpenOffice can import, to any file format that OpenOffice is capable of exporting."

Answer (score 1):

this thread or answer is old.
I tested libreoffice 4.4, I can confirm I can run libreoffice concurrently.
see my script.

```html
for odt in test*odt ; do
echo $odt
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf $odt & 
ps -ef|grep ffice 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the author already introduced Python as a valid answer:

```
import subprocess
import os, glob
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool    # wrapper around the threading module

def worker(fname, dstdir=os.path.expanduser("~")):
    subprocess.call(["libreoffice", "--headless", "--convert-to", "pdf", fname],
                    cwd=dstdir)

pool = Pool()
pool.map(worker, glob.iglob(
        os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "*appsmergeme.odt")
    ))
```

Using a thread pool instead of a process pool by `multiprocessing.dummy` is sufficient because new processes for real parallelism are spawn by `subprocess.call()` anyway.

We can set the command as well as the current working directory `cwd` directly. No need to load a `shell` for each file for just doing that. Furthermore, `os.path` enables cross-platform interoperability.

Comment: Using similar approach I don't see any difference in time taken on a 4 cpu machine

Answer (score 0):

I've written a program in golang to batch convert thousands of doc/xls files.

- define the "root" variable value to the path of your documents to convert
- already converted documents to pdf are skipped (if not, comment the check condition in the visit() function)
- here I'm using 4 threads (I have an Intel i3 with 4 cores). You can modify the value in the main() function

Sometimes it can happen that Libreoffice doesn't convert some files, so you should open it and convert them to PDF manually. Luckily, they were only 10 out of my 16.000 documents to convert.

```
package main

import (
    "os/exec"
    "sync"
    "path/filepath"
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

// root dir of your documents to convert
root := "/.../conversion-from-office/"

var tasks = make(chan *exec.Cmd, 64)

func visit(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if (f.IsDir()) {
        // fmt.Printf("Entering %s\n", path)
    } else {
        ext := filepath.Ext(path)
        if (strings.ToLower (ext) == "pdf") {
        } else {


            outfile := path[0:len(path)-len(ext)] + ".pdf"

            if _, err := os.Stat(outfile); os.IsNotExist(err) {

                fmt.Printf("Converting %s\n", path)

                outdir := filepath.Dir(path)
                tasks <- exec.Command("soffice", "--headless", "--convert-to", "pdf", path, "--outdir", outdir)
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
} 


func main() {
    // spawn four worker goroutines
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // the  ...; i < 4;... indicates that I'm using 4 threads
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            for cmd := range tasks {
                cmd.Run()
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }


    err := filepath.Walk(root, visit)
    fmt.Printf("filepath.Walk() returned %v\n", err)

    close(tasks)

    // wait for the workers to finish
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem with *unoconv*. *unoconv* internally makes use of *libreoffice*. We solved it by sending multiple files to unoconv in one invocation. So, instead of iterating over all files, we just partition the set of files into buckets, each bucket representing the o/p format. Then we make as many calls as there are buckets.

I am pretty sure *libreoffice* also has a similar mode.

Answer (score -2):

*Untested* potentially valid:

You /may/ be able to:

- Divide up the files into a number of parallel batches in some equitable way, e.g. placing them all in folders;
- Create a distinct local user account to handle each folder;
- Run Libreoffice serially as each user

e.g.

```
 for paralleluser in timlev1 timlev2 timlev3 timlev4 ; do
      su - $paralleluser -c \
         "for file in /var/spool/pdfbatches/$paralleluser ; do \
            libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf $file ; done" 
 done
```

By using `su -` you won't accidentally inherit any environment variables from your real session, so the parallel processes *shouldn't* interfere with one another (aside from competing for resources).

Keep in mind, these are likely I/O-bound tasks, so running 1 per CPU core will probably *not* speed you up so very much.

Comment: Open/Libreoffice doens't permit to run soffice.exe in parallel